# accessing magnolia resources using NetDrive

Tags: webdav, magnolia

I would like to edit some STK-Templates. I use NetDrive to access magnolia resources but this doesn't work, see the screenshot:

[image]
What did I do workng?

I also tried [this tutorial](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/WebDAV+module#WebDAVmodule-Download), but after restarting tomcat server nothing change. plz helpppp

Comment: boahhh I hate magnolia

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on mac.

I don't have Windows nor the netDrive, but looking at the screenshot I believe your connect URL is wrong. According to documentation it should be `http://<host name\[:port\]>/<magnolia context>/.webdav/<workspace>` not just `http://localhost`.

The page you mentioned above links to http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS45/WebDAV+module which imho explains that nice and clean. Try less hating and more reading ;)

Also answered in [magnolia WebDAV doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606916/magnolia-webdav-doesnt-work)

HTH,
Jan

Comment: I tried all of the URLs in the Tutorial: http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/.webdav/templates
http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/.webdav/resources
http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/.webdav/scripts
http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/.webdav/dms But without success :(

Comment: Did you try with different tool or with curl/wget to access any of those URLs to make sure they work? BTW which version of Magnolia are you using?

Comment: Yes I did. I have Magnolia Comunity Edition last version.

Comment: Is WebDAV supported in CE or only EE??

Comment: Community. BTW which version of Webdav module and of Magnolia are you using? "last version" is 5.2.4, but that looks different than the screenshot you posted originally.

Comment: magnolia-module-webdav-2.0-bundle

Answer (score 0):

I just tried tried Magnolia-5.2.4 with magnolia-module-webdav-2.0 on Windows and BitKinex version 3.2.3. It works without any problems.

But from screenshot which you posted originally I see you are using version prior Magnolia5 (4.4.x, 4.5.x).