# magnolia WebDAV doesn't work

Tags: webdav, magnolia

I have installed Magnolia `WebDAV-2.0` and try to access the `templates Folder /magnoliaAuthor/.webdav/templates/` with BitKinex. I get the error `HTTP forbidden` when I try to access the templates Folder ; See the following picture:
[image]

I read in JIRA, that `WebDAV-2.0 Version` fixes this Problem but I try it and get the same error. Calling `http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/.webdav/templates` with the browser Returns blank page, which mean for me that webdav is installed successfully. How to Access magnolia webdav?

Comment: I have the same Problem. Are u using CE or EE? Did you find solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See same discussion at http://forum.magnolia-cms.com/forum/thread.html?threadId=ea35f17c-2e59-4f54-bffd-f80515d42f61&page=1

The report from Magnolia devs was that testing with "Magnolia-5.2.4 with magnolia-module-webdav-2.0 on Windows and BitKinex version 3.2.3" all works as it should.
Also the original issue reported confirmed that all works fine as long as you have the latest version.

Pls try with the same version or double check you don't have any version conflicts.